# Airdrop doesn't work between MBP mid-2012 and iPhone 6

Tags: macbook-pro, iphone, airdrop

I read that Airdrop between iOS is since the MBP mid-2012. Although I have that Macbook I can't see my iPhone and viceversa. What can be the problem or the info that I'm misunderstanding?

PS: I have El Capitan but didn't make a clean installation.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do both devices have wifi and Bluetooth turned on?

Comment: Yes they do. Firewall is turned off btw.

Comment: Do you have the latest software updates, El Capitan 10.11.1 and iOS 9.1?

Comment: Yes, they are with the lastest updates

Comment: Actually you can get airdrop working also on other models. I found this solution: Continuity Activation Tool https://codeload.github.com/dokterdok/Continuity-Activation-Tool/zip/master

Answer (score 4):

Found [a post](https://discussions.apple.com/message/29208876#29208876) which gives this advice:

> Turn off bluetooth on your mac, delete: /Library/Preferences/com.apple.Bluetooth.plist turn bluetooth back on

I tried this and can confirm that it fixed the problem for me.